# How to use custom laravel request in a trait

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a trait that handle store method for a controller.
Also I have a custom request class for request validation.

So issue is that I want to use my custom request class as a variable in the trait store method like this:

```
trait ApiStoreTrait
{

    public function store(MyCustomRequest $request)
    {

         $this->model()::create($request->all());
         return response()->json([], 201);

    }

}
```

But as you know trait is dynamic I have to get this request class from the controller.

So how can I do this?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I think it's impossible. For what reason do you need it?

Comment: For custom requests.

Comment: ok, let's go deeper, you need validation from the custom request or something else?

Comment: You know custom request is usefull when doing custom validaiton etc.

Comment: According to your previous comment is that you need to build Custom Laravel so, I recommend using [DTO](https://dev.to/zubairmohsin33/data-transfer-object-dto-in-laravel-with-php7-4-typed-properties-2hi9). Also, can use [DTO Spatie Package](https://github.com/spatie/data-transfer-object) that will help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You can access $request object via `app('request')`. For example:

```
app('request')->cookie('X')
```

credits to **robrogers3** answer on [Unable to access request within trait](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/unable-to-access-request-within-trait).